# Get the value of a property from a Class in Form2, and that value have been set in Form1 in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is the scenario. I want to set the value of Server in Class1, i am setting the value in Form1.
Then get the value of Server in Class1 in Form2. Here is what i have.

```
class Class1
{
    private string server;

    public string Server
    {
        get { return server; }
        set { server = value; }
    }
}

//Form1 where i want to set the value of server
private void setBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 sample = new Class1();
    sample.Server = serverTxt.Text;
}

//Form2 where i want to get the value of server that i've set in Form1
private void setBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 sample = new Class1();
    string serVer = sample.Server;
}
```

I know i can't have a value of server because i declared a new instance of Class1. But is there any way that i can still get the value of Server in Form2 that i have set in Form1?

Please spare with me, i am new in C#, thanks in advance guys :D

Comment: Rather than post "This is answered", please click the checkmark next to the post which you consider the answer. Stack Overflow does not work like a forum, and this allows future readers to quickly see which solution you considered best.

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks, its noted, sorry, i'm new in stackoverflow :)

Comment: No problem, it can take a little getting used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of alternatives but static instance of Class1 would be easier.

In form1, declare/create static instance of Class1 class

```
//Form1 where i want to set the value of server
public static Class1 sample=new Class1();
private void setBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sample.Server = serverTxt.Text;
}
```

and in Form2,

```
//Form2 where i want to get the value of server that i've set in Form1
private void setBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string serVer = Form1.sample.Server;
}
```

Comment: good heavens! thanks man! that was just so easy. thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 1):

Not only you can't do that, but in your code after the execution of setBtn_Click_1 the object of type Class1 that you created is gone - this is because you only have a reference to it in the method, so when the method executes the reference is gone!

Answer (score 1):

You could send it in a constructor when creating the second form.
Something like this then

```
class Class1
{
    private string server;

    public string Server
    {
        get { return server; }
        set { server = value; }
    }
}

//form 1
private void setBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 sample = new Class1();
    sample.Server = serverTxt.Text;
    prevForm = sample;
}



//form 2
private void setBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 sample = new Class1{ Server=prevForm.Server };
}
```

For this you should keep the result or the reference to you first form somewhere so you can acces it later on

Answer (score 1):

one solution to this is to declare the server property in the Calss1 as static

```
class Class1
{
    public static string Server { get; set; }
}
```

so that you can get its value between the two forms

```
private void setBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1.Server = serverTxt.Text;
}

private void setBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string serVer = Class1.Server;
}
```

use this only if you if you have one Server for all the instances of Class1

Comment: Do not remember to add that in such case there are only one Server for all instances of Class1.

Comment: ok @Praetor12 i forgot to mention, i edited the answer, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the value of serverTxt.Text in Form1 to the Global variable(the simpliest way). Then just take the value of this global variable in Form2

Answer (score 1):

You can send the relevant data in the Form2 constructor and initialize it from Form1 (pass the data when you initialize Form2 in Form1)

[EDIT]
You could also pass the information via a database that keeps that data or using an external file that both forms have access to.